# how to force that this function to be open once a day?

Tags: javascript

this is my popunder script. I want this code be open once 24h.

```
<script>
function makePopunder(pUrl) {
    var _parent = (top != self && typeof (top["document"]["location"].toString()) === "string") ? top : self;
    var mypopunder = null;
    var pName = (Math["floor"]((Math["random"]() * 1000) + 1));
    var pWidth = window["innerWidth"];
    var pHeight = window["innerHeight"];
    var pPosX = window["screenX"];
    var pPosY = window["screenY"];
    var pWait = 3600;
    pWait = (pWait * 1000);
    var pCap = 50000;
    var todayPops = 0;
    var cookie = "_.mypopunder";
    var browser = function () {
        var n = navigator["userAgent"]["toLowerCase"]();
        var b = {
            webkit: /webkit/ ["test"](n),
            mozilla: (/mozilla/ ["test"](n)) && (!/(compatible|webkit)/ ["test"](n)),
            chrome: /chrome/ ["test"](n),
            msie: (/msie/ ["test"](n)) && (!/opera/ ["test"](n)),
            firefox: /firefox/ ["test"](n),
            safari: (/safari/ ["test"](n) && !(/chrome/ ["test"](n))),
            opera: /opera/ ["test"](n)
        };
        b["version"] = (b["safari"]) ? (n["match"](/.+(?:ri)[\/: ]([\d.]+)/) || [])[1] : (n["match"](/.+(?:ox|me|ra|ie)[\/: ]([\d.]+)/) || [])[1];
        return b;
    }();

    function isCapped() {
        try {
            todayPops = Math["floor"](document["cookie"]["split"](cookie + "Cap=")[1]["split"](";")[0]);
        } catch (err) {};
        return (pCap <= todayPops || document["cookie"]["indexOf"](cookie + "=") !== -1);
    };

    function doPopunder(pUrl, pName, pWidth, pHeight, pPosX, pPosY) {
        if (isCapped()) {
            return;
        };
        var sOptions = "toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,location=yes,statusbar=yes,menubar=no,resizable=1,width=" + pWidth.toString() + ",height=" + pHeight.toString() + ",screenX=" + pPosX + ",screenY=" + pPosY;
        document["onclick"] = function (e) {
            if (isCapped() || window["pop_clicked"] == 1 || pop_isRightButtonClicked(e)) {
                //return;
            };
            window["pop_clicked"] = 1;
            mypopunder = _parent["window"]["open"](pUrl, pName, sOptions);
            if (mypopunder) {
                var now = new Date();
                document["cookie"] = cookie + "=1;expires=" + new Date(now["setTime"](now["getTime"]() + pWait))["toGMTString"]() + ";path=/";
                now = new Date();
                document["cookie"] = cookie + "Cap=" + (todayPops + 1) + ";expires=" + new Date(now["setTime"](now["getTime"]() + (84600 * 1000)))["toGMTString"]() + ";path=/";
                pop2under();
            };
        };
    };

    function pop2under() {
        try {
            mypopunder["blur"]();
            mypopunder["opener"]["window"]["focus"]();
            window["self"]["window"]["blur"]();
            window["focus"]();
            if (browser["firefox"]) {
                openCloseWindow();
            };
            if (browser["webkit"]) {
                openCloseTab();
            };
        } catch (e) {};
    };

    function openCloseWindow() {
        var ghost = window["open"]("about:blank");
        ghost["focus"]();
        ghost["close"]();
    };

    function openCloseTab() {
        var ghost = document["createElement"]("a");
        ghost["href"] = "about:blank";
        ghost["target"] = "PopHelper";
        document["getElementsByTagName"]("body")[0]["appendChild"](ghost);
        ghost["parentNode"]["removeChild"](ghost);
        var clk = document["createEvent"]("MouseEvents");
        clk["initMouseEvent"]("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, true, false, false, true, 0, null);
        ghost["dispatchEvent"](clk);
        window["open"]("about:blank", "PopHelper")["close"]();
    };

    function pop_isRightButtonClicked(e) {
        var rightclick = false;
        e = e || window["event"];
        if (e["which"]) {
            rightclick = (e["which"] == 3);
        } else {
            if (e["button"]) {
                rightclick = (e["button"] == 2);
            };
        };
        return rightclick;
    };
    if (isCapped()) {
        return;
    } else {
        doPopunder(pUrl, pName, pWidth, pHeight, pPosX, pPosY);
    };
}

makePopunder("http://p30rank.ir/");
</script>
```

I'm not very familiar to javascript.
but i have a second code that do this job for me :

```
function getCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
  {
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x==c_name)
    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}

function setCookie(c_name,value)
{
var exdays= 12;
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setHours(exdate.getHours() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
// var wxyzabcdefab = 1468575237; var wxyzabcdefab = 1468575237; var wxyzabcdefab = 1468575237; var wxyzabcdefab = 1468575237;
var wxyzabcdefab = 1468576261;
function checkCookie()
{
var username1=getCookie(randd);
var usernam = "sendshod";
if(username1==null){
window.open('#','_parent','toolbar=1,location=1,directories=1,status=1,menubar=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1');
window.focus();
}
if(username1=="" | username1==null){
if(window.open('http://p30rank.ir/p30pop.php?id=1&secid='+secid+'&wxyzabcdefab='+wxyzabcdefab ,'_blank','toolbar=1,scrollbars=1,location=1,statusbar=1,menubar=1,resizable=1')){
window.focus();
setCookie(randd,usernam);
}
}
}
document.onclick = checkCookie;
if ((window.XMLHttpRequest == undefined) && (ActiveXObject != undefined)) window.onload = checkCookie;
```

but second code is not compatible with google chrome . first code is fine.

can i use first makePopunder("http://p30rank.ir/"); to secode code like this :

```
if(makePopunder("http://p30rank.ir/")){
window.focus();
setCookie(randd,usernam);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.
set cookie and then get cookie

```
function setCookie(name, value, time) {
    var expires = new Date();

    expires.setTime(expires.getTime() + time);

    document.cookie = name + '=' + value + '; path=/;' + '; expires=' + expires.toGMTString();
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var cookies = document.cookie.toString().split('; ');
    var cookie, c_name, c_value;

    for (var n = 0; n < cookies.length; n++) {
        cookie = cookies[n].split('=');
        c_name = cookie[0];
        c_value = cookie[1];

        if (c_name == name) {
            return c_value;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```